# Different cell height in html table

Tags: html

I need html table like below template.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using 'rowspan' ? I tried

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>                            
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

but it is not working as I expected.

Comment: What data structure do you have where it makes sense to express it as a *table* with *that* layout?!

Comment: I have to make pdf invoice template. I know there are other ways to achieve this but just want to know if there is solution using only rowspan

Comment: Can you use `CSS` and `DIVS` ? I would be looking into `grid layout` if you have that possiblity

Comment: I'd look into using a CSS Grid layout instead of a table structure.

Comment: Thank, guys. It turned out what I tried is working but the row is only stretching if I put some block element inside the cell.